# Synchronous socket second receive() call not return / time out

Tags: c#, sockets, synchronous

I have a Synchronous client socket talking to a LRS (Long Range Systems) transmitter, it takes XML input and TCPIP connection. I am able to create a connection with the device and receive an response once connected; but when I tried to send some texts and call Receive again, no reply or eventually time out. Can you please explain why?

My sample code:

```
Socket tcpSocket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
System.Net.IPAddress[] IPs = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("valid_IP_address");
tcpSocket.Connect(IPs[0], PORT_NUMBER);
int nBytes = 0;
byte[] RcvBytes = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
if (tcpSocket.Connected)
{
    tcpSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;   //1 minute timeout
    //connected is true and below Receive call returns some bytes
    //RcvBytes contains a valid response, ie, <LRSN services="blah, blah" ... />
    nBytes = tcpSocket.Receive(RcvBytes, 0, tcpSocket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
}

//below Send returns 8 bytes, the lenth of "SomeText"
nBytes = tcpSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("SomeText"));

//*** FAILS, below Receive call never returns, eventually time out
nBytes = tcpSocket.Receive(RcvBytes, 0, tcpSocket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
```

Comment: Further to my question. After receive time out, I am able to call tcpSocket.Disconnect and the device shows no clients connected, so it seems there are still handshakes.

Comment: use wireshark or equivalent to see if any traffic is returned after you send "SomeText". If there is no response then `Receive` is behaving as expected

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried sending "<Login/>", expecting a <LoginAck> message returns specifying success or error. I also tried sending "<PageRequest id="1">..." text, which is another set of valid message to the device, but still no response.

Comment: Without determining if any data actually comes back by using a packet sniffer, it's very difficult to say where the problem lies

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did try WireShark and it seems ACK did send back but len is 0. 

    Send:    21125→3700 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65279 Len=8
    Receive: 3700→21125 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=9 Win=859 Len=0

Comment: That's an Ack for the send, not a reply for the receive call to pick up on

Answer (score 1):

I think you've probably run into this issue:

> LRSN Message Transport All messages are XML based. With some XML
>   parsers, it is difficult to process a continuous XML stream. To ease
>   parsing incoming messages, the following message framing scheme is
>   used: • Newline characters (’\n’) are used to delimit the end of a
>   message. The data between two newlines should form a parsable XML
>   document (i.e. all tags balanced).

So try sending some newlines through.

Comment: But I am only sending the simple login message below:
`<Login user="" passwd="" services="NetPage" />`

I shall receive <LoginAck> message, but none is received. It seems that the transmitter doesn't understand the message I sent and completely ignores it.

Can someone please post a working sample as I couldn't find any resource on line. Thank heaps!

Comment: Every message, including a login message, has to be terminated with a newline/line feed character '\n' (ASCII 10). You will not receive a <LoginAck> until you send `<Login user="" passwd="" services="NetPage" />\n`

Comment: OMG, I couldn't believe that is the reason! I've been digging around for updated API doco... BTW, I couldn't find one.

Thank you very much for solving this myth!

Comment: I tried to mark this as answer but encountered error... Not sure if it is because you are a Guest. Thanks again!